# Fix All Commit Messages in Git

Tags: git, git-commit

I am in process of migrating a subversion repository to git.  We enforce a commit message format like so:

`[#<Issue Number Here>] The commit message.`

During the migration, I noticed that some people put a new line into the commit message like this:

```
[#<Issue Number Here>]
The commit message.
```

I'll be adding a pre-commit hook to enforce our message format once the migration is complete, but how can I fix existing all commit messages after I've used `git svn` to clone the source repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter fix-imported-msg.sh HEAD
```

(you need to write your own fix-imported-msg.sh script to take the original message on stdin, and write the corrected version to stdout).

This will be slightly more complicated if you have multiple branches, if you've already pushed the imported repo, etc.

Comment: I have not pushed yet.  Won't this only fix the HEAD of whatever branch I'm on?  I want to fix all commits in the repository that are incorrect.  I don't mind manually going to each branch, but I can't go to every commit.

Comment: Read the linked docs for filter-branch. It rewrites entire branches.